# Push-button BCD counter circuit

Tags: ttl, multisim

I am trying to reinvent the wheel apparently... I want to create a one-digit BCD counter that increases on a button push and resets to zero when reaches nine. 
I have just finished a circuit for BCD to 7-segments encoder.

Can anybody give me the basic idea of how should I do this?

Comment: Such a question with no evidence of research is closed.

Comment: What "evidence of research" do you want? There are tutorials that show how to use an already made counter everywhere on the Internet. So that's is not useful at all for me here

Comment: Then try to find out how this ready-made counter is implemented. You could have a look in that counter's datasheet and see how it is build up. Hint: flip-flops !

Comment: even bigger hint http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electronic/bincount.html

Comment: "What evidence do you want? There are tutorials..." -> I'd say a link and a sentence starting with "I don't understand how they did..." or "I think this does.... is that right?" Or any such combination.

Comment: I think he wants to know how to build a counter from AND/OR/Inverter gates only, which is good !!! Using a micro as a counter: too easy ;-)  Flip-flops = more fun :-)

Comment: Read his comments overall. I am utterly flabbergasted [tm] at the arrogant attitude to would be learners here. Dwayne did well, and Alex added some useful links, but here you have an obviously keen learner and the group attitude is to treat them as badly as possible. Very sad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are apparently on the right track.  Now all you need is a binary counter that resets when it gets to 9.  That's a total of 10 discrete steps (0..9)

Basic theory should have told you that you need a minimum of 4 flip-lops.  3 flip-flops will count to a maximum of 7 (2^3 -> 0..7), so you need to add the 4th stage to get past 7.

The problem is that 4 flip-flops will count to 15 before rolling over back to 0.

There are two methods used to force a roll-over from 9 back to 0.

1) Use an AND gate to detect the 10th step and use that to reset all the flip-flops back to 0.

The problem with this technique is that you get a very short glitch when the counter gets to "10" before resetting.  This is usually not a problem but you need to be aware that it occurs.

This is a simple counter consisting of 4- toggle flip-flops and one AND gate.  The toggle FFs can be made from D or J-K flip-slops.  The counter stages can be configured as either asynchronous (ripple counter) or synchronous.

2) Use J-K flip-flops and logic gates to construct a counter such that the next clock pulse after the 9th causes the J-K inputs to force the next clock pulse to go back to zero.  These are almost always synchronous counters: all of the outputs change on the active clock edge.

There is another class of counter known as a "Johnson Counter".  This is a counter where there is a single flip-flop for each step in the count.  In other words, a 10 step counter (0..9) would have 10 FFs.  The useful benefit offered by this class of counter is that only one output is active (either HI or LO) at any instant in time.

In other words, a Johnson counter doesn't require decoding to get 10 discrete outputs.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is very useful for me. My knowledge is very fragile yet, because I've just started a course, so that's why I didn't know what to ask for :))

Answer (score 2):

To give you an idea how these counters are made with JK flip-flops take a look at the 7493 on page 4 in in this datasheet http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74ls90.pdf.
The 7490 is a decade counter while 7493 is just a binary counter. The 7493 has the AND gate (mentioned above) already built-in. If you connect R0(1) to QB and R0(2) to QD the counter will reset when it reaches 1010.
I used to play a lot with these parts when I was a kid right after they were released by TI 40 years ago. Good old days..

Comment: +1 - and a few more +1's elsewhere too having looked over your answers :-)